# JavaScript / Vue.js match two array based on nameValue and delete array item which do not match

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

How can I match two array based on nameValue?

So in below example, delete array items which do not match based on nameValue and keep the productPrice:

```
    const allCombinations = ref([]);
    const allValuesForProduct = ref([]);
    //
    allCombinations.value = [
        {nameValue: 'blue/m/regular', productPrice: null},
        {nameValue: 'red/m/regular', productPrice: null},
        {nameValue: 'pink/m/regular', productPrice: null},
    ]

    allValuesForProduct.value = [
        {nameValue: 'blue', productPrice: 666},
        {nameValue: 'red', productPrice: 666},
        {nameValue: 'pink', productPrice: 666},
        {nameValue: 'blue/m/regular', productPrice: 99},
        {nameValue: 'red/m/regular', productPrice: 99},
        {nameValue: 'pink/m/regular', productPrice: 99},
    ]
```

End result should look like this:

```
    const allCombinations = ref([]);
    const allValuesForProduct = ref([]);
    //
    allCombinations.value = [
        {nameValue: 'blue/m/regular', productPrice: null},
        {nameValue: 'red/m/regular', productPrice: null},
        {nameValue: 'pink/m/regular', productPrice: null},
    ]

    allValuesForProduct.value = [
        {nameValue: 'blue/m/regular', productPrice: 99},
        {nameValue: 'red/m/regular', productPrice: 99},
        {nameValue: 'pink/m/regular', productPrice: 99},
    ]
```

Comment: you forgot the code you've tried - it's a simple filter/includes combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 allCombinations.value = allCombinations.value.filter(comb => {
   return allValuesForProduct.value.some(val => {
       return val.nameValue === comb.nameValue
   })
 })
 
 allValuesForProduct.value = allValuesForProduct.value.filter(val => {
   return allCombinations.value.some(comb => {
       return comb.nameValue === val.nameValue
   })  
 })
```